# uploading via google api from remote url

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to upload a file to via Google ruby API client. 
This works

```
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new('test.jpg', 'image/jpeg')
```

but this does not work

```
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new('http://www.somedomain.com/test.jpg', 'image/jpeg')
```

How would i upload media from a remote server such as s3?

Comment: Use `Net::HTTP` or something to download to your server first? Or is that not a viable solution?

Comment: Yeah i suppose my next option is to create a tempfile. but it seems wasteful to download the file on my server just to send it to another remote server. For an image its not a big deal, but it may be a problem for a video. I was hoping there the api would handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the solution i wanted to this question. I ended up using Ruby Tempfile class which will download external files to my server in a temp folder and delete garbage collect once its done.

There is a great explanation of how to use this class [here](http://viget.com/extend/make-remote-files-local-with-ruby-tempfile)